# How to hide Log In and Sign Up event when Login success in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making a website about sales  . I got some issues when I created Account part.

Details of my problem is:When I login success I create `Session["user"]` to get information of user
and then I want to hide Login and SignUp event to show Logout and My Information event

```
<ul class="login-signup">
    <li id="logIn"><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Account")"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>Log In</a></li>
    <li id="signUp"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li id="myInfor"><a href="#">My information</a></li>
    <li id="logOut"><a href="@Url.Action("Logout","Account")"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i>Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

I create script to do that as the following

```
<script>
if (@Session["user"]!=null) {
            $("#logIn").hide();
            $("#signUp").hide();
            $("#myInfor").show();
            $("#logOut").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#logIn").show();
            $("#signUp").show();
            $("#myInfor").hide();
            $("#logOut").hide();
        }
</script>
```

It is not working as i expected.Its show off all 4.

It doesn't seem working in if else block above.
Please help me.sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if statement` inside your `ul` like this :

```
<ul class="login-signup">

    @if (Session["user"]!=null)
    {
        <li id="myInfor"><a href="#">My information</a></li>
        <li id="logOut"><a href="@Url.Action("Logout","Account")"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i>Log Out</a></li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li id="logIn"><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Account")"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>Log In</a></li>
        <li id="signUp"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    }

</ul>
```